# Should I write a monograph for myself?

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, monograph

My dissertation is going to be a [thesis by publication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis_by_publication). I am going to publish a couple of papers and put those into one document with a couple of leading words (another 20 pages or so) and this is going to be my thesis. I feel that the monograph I wrote for my master thesis (which was pretty extensive) was actually pretty helpful as a reference now (I am continuing the research on the same topic). Thus I would like to know: *Should I write a monograph for myself?* Obviously I am not going to publish that, so I won't have all the work with writing it nicely (or at least more nicely than I personally need). My mentor (who is not my doctor father) told me this is too much work and I should rather use that time to publish more. What do you think? I am researching of A.I. and Machine Learning, thus I will have a lot of math and a lot of programming. The monograph I would write would be about the math, not the programming (that should document itself).

The comments seem to misunderstand a couple of things:

1. My mentor is not my doctor father. My mentor has not say in anything and no involvement - he is just there to give me tips.
2. There is no question what my thesis will be. It will be a thesis by publication. The monograph would just be for myself.
3. I cannot "publish a paper based on the thesis": My thesis is going to consist out of multiple (about 6) publications.

Comment: Didn’t you write things down nicely in your paper?

Comment: Really, this is your call, especially, if your mentor essentially supports a quick solution in the way of dissertation by publication (some don't, they want a book). The monograph is, of course, a learning experience, which may be just the thing you want. But nobody can really answer this question. Writing a monograph is a different animal than a paper; its length imposes totally different way of organising the writing than a paper.

Comment: "this is too much work and I should rather use that time to publish more": I agree. Rather, try to see if you can publish a paper based on the thesis.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: No. Paper are written in such a way that they should be understood by themselves. Thus I would simply everything that is not needed for this particular paper. Thus I leave out generalizing stuff. E.g. parameter in formulas that are zero parameter for this particular paper will be left out. E.g. the formula can be weighted with a parameter, but in this paper the weight is always 1, so in this paper we leave the parameter out.

Comment: Well, I'm writing a thesis by publication too, and it has basically two parts before all the papers, the first beeing an introduction to the topic which is about 30 pages long in my work. Wouldn't it be possible to fit such information there.

Comment: @DSVA: I want to write as little as possible "offical" stuff - that needs correction which is time consuming. Instead i want to write "extra" stuff for myself - that I can write as I see fit.